# Checking if a Spotify user follows an artist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spotify

I am creating a rails app that checks whether a user follows an artist on spotify. I have the following code to check if this is the case.

```
def personalise(acts) 
    acts_with_rank = acts.collect{|act|{:value => rank(act), :label => act.name}}
end

def rank(act)
    spotify_user = RSpotify::User.new(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    artist = RSpotify::Artist.search(act.name).first
    binding.remote_pry
        if spotify_user.follows?(artist)
            10
        else
            0
        end
end
```

The problem is, every act ends up with 10 as its value in the hash, regardless of whether or not the user is actually following the artist. I am using remote-pry to check whether or not true or false is returned for each iteration of the if statement, and although it is correctly returning true or false depending on whether or not the user is following the artist, something else seems to make the if statements return 0. Any help would be appreciated on this as I'm sure I'm just looking at this for too long and can't see something stupid that I've done!

Comment: Haven't used this library before and I've never done Ruby, but browsing the code makes me curious to try out how it reacts to timeouts or if a server error is returned instead of a boolean. Either this blocking request returns an error that's being interpreted as a falsy value, or the exception is propagated upwards the stack. Interpreting an error as falsy would explain this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out what was going wrong

```
spotify_user.follows?(artist)
```

returns an *array* of booleans, to access the boolean of interest here, the simple fix was:

```
        if spotify_user.follows?(artist)[0]
            10
        else
            0
        end
```